# ошибка при запуске unity игры на андроиде

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

до компиляции, в unity все работает нормально, ошибок нет. когда я компилирую, скидываю на телефон и пытаюсь запустить, то после появления значка unity игра вылетает. сообщение об ошибке в скринах.

скрины сделаны с телефона redmi 9t. с redmi 9 первый раз вылетает, потом запускается нормально.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Два вопроса (не замечай, что первый глупый) :  1. Ты делал билд для телефонов? 2. Какой у тебя телефон?

Comment: да, точно для телефона. в настройках билда у новой версии я ничего не менял, а прошлая версия работает нормально. 
тут скрины с телефона redmi 9t. на нём при каждом запуске вылетает. так же я проверял с redmi 9 на нём первый раз вылетает второй запускается нормально. 
выше писали чтобы я вместо скринов текст использовал, однако я больше не могу добиться вылета этого сообщения. оно просто закрывается без ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в проекте были слишком большие изображения. из за большого размера они не грузились